# finding overlapping time in a group

Tags: r, dataframe

In each household I want to define an indicator whose determined if a driver is available for a passenger or not. the driver is available if his/her trip start  at most 1 hour after passengers's trip.

example:

```
      household    person     mode       start
           1         1         car        7:20
           1         1         car        8:00
           1         1         car        8:30
           1         2       non-car      7:30
           1         3       non-car      7:15
           1         4         car        7:00
           2         1          car       7:00
           2         2        non-car      9:00
```

in the first household driver can give a ride since his trip is 30 minutes after than second person also he can give a ride to third person . in the second household no.

output

```
      household    person     mode       start      indicator
           1         1         car        8:00          1 
           1         2       non-car      7:30          1
           1         3       non-car      7:15          1
           2         1          car       7:00          0
           2         2        non-car      9:00         0
```

then I want to put these matched rows (indicator is 1) next to each other

output

```
      household    person     mode       start      indicator   household    person     mode       start      indicator
           1         1         car        8:00          1       2         2       non-car      7:30          1
           1         1         car        8:00          1       3         2       non-car      7:15          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'start' to datetime class with `as.POSIXct`, grouped by 'household', check whether the `diff`ernece of 'start' is less than or equal to 1, coerce the logical to binary with `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 mutate(start = as.POSIXct(start, format = '%H:%M')) %>% 
 group_by(household) %>% 
 mutate(indicator = as.integer(any(diff(start) <= 1)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   household [2]
#  household person mode    start               indicator
#      <int>  <int> <chr>   <dttm>                  <int>
#1         1      1 car     2019-09-03 08:00:00         1
#2         1      2 non-car 2019-09-03 07:30:00         1
#3         2      1 car     2019-09-03 07:00:00         0
#4         2      2 non-car 2019-09-03 09:00:00         0
```

---

To get the second output, we can make use of the `pivot_wider` from the devel version of `tidyr`

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(startn = as.POSIXct(start, format = '%H:%M')) %>% 
  group_by(household) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = as.integer(any(diff(startn) <= 1))) %>%  
  filter(indicator == 1) %>% 
  select(-startn) %>% 
  group_by(household) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = c(household, person, mode, start, indicator))
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  household_1 household_2 person_1 person_2 mode_1 mode_2  start_1 start_2 indicator_1 indicator_2
#        <int>       <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>         <int>       <int>
#1           1           1        1        2 car    non-car 8:00    7:30              1           1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(household = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), person = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), mode = c("car", "non-car", "car", "non-car"), start = c("8:00", 
"7:30", "7:00", "9:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: how about car and non-car option? I do not match 2 non-cars or 2 cars!!!!!

Comment: also give me this error: Error: Column `indicator` must be length 14 (the group size) or one, not 13

Comment: @shere let me recheck

Comment: for the first output I can not see how to make sure non-cars will not matched

Comment: @shere Here, I assume that there are only two rows per each group and non-cars are the second one

Comment: No actually there are more, I will update my example

Comment: @shere that would be great

Comment: @shere It is working fine for me `df2 %>%  mutate(start = as.POSIXct(start, format = '%H:%M')) %>% 
  group_by(household) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = as.integer(any(diff(start) <= 1)))`

Comment: 2 non-cars in the first family also have the same situation, their start differ by1

Comment: @shere So, you want to check only between the first 'car' and next 'non-car' for each household?

Comment: @shere  WIll there by multiple 'car' 'mode' for each 'household' ?

Comment: yes, there are some driver and some non-driver, I almost get all 1 by your code which is not correct

Comment: do you think the code can be fixed for that? it is important for me

Comment: @shere Can you update your post with an example that doesn't work with this code?  In that way, it becomes easier to fix